# random list object and instantiate gameObject

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I will use Pokemon as an example: I have a list of 10 elements, each element contains: string name, GameObject, int hp and mana int, int rarity.

I need after every click or tap, is made a random, even so good, but imagine that these 10 Pokemons, 2 of them are very rare.

after the random, will check out common or rare pokemon. if common, it will be made another radom and will choose only 1. if rare pokemon, choose one of two available. I believe it is very confusing.

the problem and I'm not managing to make the random list not instantiate the object. currently my code this as follows ..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Pokemons : MonoBehaviour 
{

    [Serializable]
    public class ListPokemons
    {
        public string name;
        public GameObject componentObjc;
        public int hp;
        public int mana;
        public int rarity;    
    }

    public ListPokemons[] pokeAtributs;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        List<ListPokemons> list = pokeAtributs.ToList ();
        //ListPokemons pokemon = list.FirstOrDefault (r => r.componentObjc != null);
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity 5. I am Portuguese and all the text has been translated using google translate.

Comment: Hint: Rare elements are a random number between 100 and 10,000(low possibility of getting the same number twice) then assign a flag as _rare_. Common elements is a random between 0 and 100(higher possibility), also assign a flag _common_.

Comment: You need distribution (math). But, what I tend to do in cases like this is I decide how many rare pokemons and how many common I will give out. Let's say 98 common, 2 rares. I do 2 random rolls 1-100 to decide where the rares go, or even build a fix size list, filling up accordingly and not rolling game time, just picking out the next list item; this way you will be "even-handed" as otherwise (also math: fair coin) you might won't be. BTW why ListPokemons is not a struct instead? Also use Awake() instead of Start() if you manipulate GObjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sounds like you should organize your rare and common in two different lists.

Something like this maybe (it's a mockup):

```
// fill these in the inspector. you don't need the extra arrays.
public List<ListPokemons> rarePokemon;
public List<ListPokemons> commonPokemon;

...

void PickPokemon()
{
    int rarityRoll = Random.Range(0, 100);
    if(rarityRoll < 80)
    {
        // choose something from common
        int roll = Random.Range(0, commonPokemon.Count);
        // instantiate
        Instantiate(commonPokemon[roll].componentObjc, new Vector3(5, 5, 5), Quaternion.identity);
    }
    else
    {
        int roll = Random.Range(0, rarePokemon.Count);
        // instantiate
        Instantiate(rarePokemon[roll].componentObjc, new Vector3(5, 5, 5), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

If you have another list you can add another roll around this.

And I don't think you need to actually initialize the public arrays to a size via code. That can be done in the inspector. (Edit: Actually you must not do that because you want to populate the list before runtime.)

`Random.Range(int a, int b)` is from a (inclusive) to b (exclusive).

Edit 2:
I guess since your arrays will be converted to lists anyways you can just get rid of the arrays and make the lists public or work with the arrays directly and remove the lists (in this case you need to use `Length` instead of `Count`).

Comment: tks but, commonPokemon.Count or rarePokemon.Count, does not exist in current context..

Comment: My mistake, obviously they need to be members. I edit that.

Comment: I not yet tested because they lack complete a little code here before you can test. but the error disappeared and everything seems right in the inspector.

I would be happy to add you to skype me, sometimes it would be great to have a few ideas.

morenito-green-eyes@hotmail.com

Comment: Sorry, but I'm actually not using skype. But there are platforms like stackoverflow here to ask questions and get suggestions. (There is also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ which will work with the same account like here.)

Comment: It is working here.
but always appears the same common pokemon or even rare pokemon ...

Comment: This is the worst you can do as of an implementation. Not the code, the way you decide to give out rare/common/[other qualities] items. See my original comment at the question (especially "fair coin"). I.e. this way some players will grind forever and don't get anything cool, while others will swim in rares and specials. But, if asker is happy, his game will work like that...

Comment: @Mark This was just a mockup to give an idea of how to do some random roll (multiple after another) and the numbers are just some quick pick. If you want to make it more random you would probably have none consecutive blocks (like 5, 15, 25, ... = rare or something like that). Imagine that you would want to check what will be in a chest. E.g. first decide food or equipment. If the later will it be a weapon or some armor. If a weapon which type and so on until you get it finally. I think this is what the question was aiming for. I think there is a term for this, but I can't recall it.

Comment: @GunnarB. I understand this is a mockup. Like I said: The approach is wrong, not the code or the numbers. Read about the two math thesis I mentioned: distribution and the more important guy: fair coin. Long story short, random is random: It is possible your player will never get any rare item/pokemon/whatever (and lose interest in the game) and another one is swimming in it (and lose game balance, then interest in the game). This is why I prefer a healthy distribution instead of a random (a well written code will look random to the players)

Comment: @Mark This is what the OP asks for.  Is it rare or not, then pick one from that group.  While not a good solution for the example (since the  non-rare group could have many more options than the rare, causing the rare to not be rare), it achieves the goal which your solution would not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that public `ListPokemons[] pokeAtributs;` is never initialized before you did `List<ListPokemons> list = pokeAtributs.ToList ();`

Simply initialize the array with the `new` keyword then it should work.

```
[Serializable]
public class ListPokemons
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject componentObjc;
    public int hp;
    public int mana;
    public int rarity;    
}

public ListPokemons[] pokeAtributs;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    //You are missing this part in your code (10 pokeAtributs  )
    pokeAtributs = new pokeAtributs[10];

    //Now you can do your stuff
    List<ListPokemons> list = pokeAtributs.ToList ();

}
```